# Writing several fields in one row in a csv with python

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models

I'm working on improving some open-source code for a psychological test.
For an output of data, I'm using python's CSV module, which works fine in itself. The data output is dependent on the Django model (trials) and the respective database entry and I want to add the data from another model (participant) to the CSV. So far I only managed to add the required entries in a new row but this basically renders the CSV unusable for further use in statistics programs.
In short what I get:

```
headers of database entry 1
headers of database entry 2
values of database entry 1
values of database entry 2
```

But what I want is the output to look like this:

```
headers of database entry 1 followed  by 2
values of database entry 1 followed by 2
```

This is what the important part of the export looks like.

```
def export_as_csv(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    headers, fields = zip(*export_info_trial)
    headers_participant, fields_participant = zip(*export_info_participant)
    zipFile = ZipFile(in_memory, 'w')
    for participant in queryset:                        
        rows = [headers_participant] + [headers] 
        participants = Participant.objects.filter(id=participant.id)
        trials = Trial.objects.filter(participant=participant.id)
        for participant_value_list in participants.values_list(*fields_participant):
            rows.append([unicode(v) for v in participant_value_list])
        for trial_value_list in trials.values_list(*fields):
            rows.append([unicode(v) for v in trial_value_list])
```

I do understand that the output as it is now is caused by me calling rows.append twice but right now I don't have any Idea how to combine these two calls cleverly (or at all).

edit:
The writer is called as follows:

```
f = StringIO()
writer = UnicodeWriter(f)                                               
for row in rows:
  writer.writerow(row)
```

I also added the preceding part of the function above.

I thank everyone for any help!

Comment: A suggestion, look at DictWriter. Its great when you want to generate a record for a single row and write it in csv file.

Comment: I think you need to merge these lists. Add the list into a resultant list and then iterate it. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **writerow** of csv.writer of python's CSV, like this :

```
def export_as_csv(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    headers, fields = zip(*export_info_trial)
    headers_participant, fields_participant = zip(*export_info_participant)
    zipFile = ZipFile(in_memory, 'w')
    rows = [headers_participant,headers] 
    result_row = []
    result_row.append(rows)
    for participant in queryset:                        
        row1 = []
        row2 = []
        participants = Participant.objects.filter(id=participant.id)    
        trials = Trial.objects.filter(participant=participant.id)               
        for participant_value_list in participants.values_list(*fields_participant):
            row1.append(unicode(v) for v in participant_value_list)
        for trial_value_list in trials.values_list(*fields):
            row2.append(unicode(v) for v in trial_value_list)
        row = row1 + row2
        result_row.append(row)

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)                                           
    for row in result_row:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

By **writerow**, you will get a list inside **result_row** in the same row of CSV.

Comment: the writer is already implemented like this: 
`f = StringIO()
        writer = UnicodeWriter(f)                                               
        for row in rows:
            writer.writerow(row)` 
where UnicodeWriter is basically a the simple writer modified. I also tried your solution but the entries as lists don't seem too useful in my case.
Thank you anyway!

Comment: @TimS thats what i am saying. You dont need to iterate rows with for loop. Just use my updated answer.

Comment: I do, because I have several entries that need to be printed into the CSV. Basically, in my test case, every CSV created should have eleven rows: one for the header and ten for the test results of one conducted test. However if I don't iterate, everything is put into the first row. Maybe my description of the required output is ambiguous. I want a row of headers and then several rows of content, whereas every row is getting its value from two different models. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @TimS for this, I think you need to merge these lists.Updating my answer.

Comment: This unfortunately does not work with UnicodeWriter. Using csv.writer actually gives out the data in the rows as I want to but it also gives out all the other characters in the list such as the brackets.
When I switch back to UnicodeWrite I get a _'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'_ error.
But apart from that it does what I want and I am really grateful for that!

Comment: @TimS You said **apart from that it does what I want** then you should accpet this answer.

Comment: @TimS Updated my asnwer. Please note those changesa and after applying them,there should not be any extra brackets. Thanks.